# How to Pass Textbox Value to Method or Function

Tags: c#, textbox, asp.net-3.5

I have a class CURPRFC that contains the following:

```
static public string CalcRFC(string firstname, string lastname, string middlename, string    date)
```

I'm calling this method/function in my codebehind as follows:

```
CURPRFC.CalcRFC(txtfirstname.text, txtlastname.text, txtmidlename.text, txtdate.text)
```

where each of the values are textbox values.  However, I receive an error stating:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My C# is a bit weak.  I think I need to change my textbox text values to strings, but am not sure of how to go about this.  Am I on the right track?

Your help is most appreciated!

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember that C# is case-sensitive. TextBox doesn't have a `text` property, but it does have a `Text` property:

```
CURPRFC.CalcRFC(txtfirstname.Text, txtlastname.Text,
                txtmidlename.Text, txtdate.Text);
```

(I'd also suggest that you think about naming clarity - conventionally C# variables use `camelCasing` to indicate word breaks, and a class named "CURPRFC" is far from self-explanatory.)